# Hot reload doesn't work on Flutter (VS Code)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I hot reload the Flutter code it shows hot restarting instead and takes a lot of time. How can I do a hot reload?

[image]

Comment: You need to save the document to trigger the `hot reload`.

Comment: Save main.dart file first and then `hot reload` or `hot restart`

Answer (score 0):

Their is an alternative way of doing this that doesn't take time, and it works on Saving for Hot reload

First, stop the current flutter run

in vs-code
Goto `Run > Run Without debugging`

or simply Ctrl + F5 on windows

That command will run your project

and it will give you a pop up inside vs-code[image]

click on the refresh like button for Hot Restart

Ctrl + S for Hot reload